# UIButton : Background Image setting Issue when button state is highlighted?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibutton

I have an UIButton, I need to change button's image when button is tapped. Button's background images are set in ViewDidLoad method. Pls refer images attached on this thread.

1. When I tap on button first time, button property will be changed to selected and "arrow_right.png" image will be set to our Button.

[image]

2.On second tap, I observed that when button state is highlighted, But it's background image is not setting. You can see some blur effect instead.

[image]

My concern is I saw while toggling UIButton, image is not getting set for highlighted state. when button's state changing from Selected to Normal.
Is it a bug or my mistake?

Thank you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [testButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [testButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_pressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
  [testButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_pressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

}
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender 
{
  UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
  button.selected = !button.selected;

  if (button.selected)
  {
      [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_right.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_right.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
      [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_right.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
  }
  else
  {
      [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_left.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_left.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
      [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_left.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry frd, I was editing my post. Sorry for your in-convince.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender 
{
  UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
 if(button.selected) {
 [button setSelected:NO]
} else {
 [button setSelected:YES]
}

}
```

i diddn't understand why you need to set image again, all you need to do is set its selected property , button will behave as you expected

Comment: I am changing selected property just by **button.selected = !button.selected;**. My concern is I saw while toggling UIButton, image is not getting set for highlighted state. when button's state changing from Selected to Normal.